# How to convert selected files in S3 bucket into snowflake stage in order to load data into snowflake using python and boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to stage files which are in s3 bucket.first of all i find the latest file which upload to the given bucket and then i need to make those files into stage.not the whole bucket. for example let say i have bucket called topic. inside that i have 2 folders topic1 and topic2. those 2 folders has newly upload 2 files.in this case i need to make those newly upload file into stage in order to load those data into snowflake.i want to do this using python and boto3. i already built a code to find the latest file, but i don't know how make them as stage.when i used the **CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE** command with for loop for each file it will only create a stage for the last file. Not creating stage for each file. How should i do this?

` def download_s3_files(self):

```
s3_object = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=self.s3_acc_key, aws_secret_access_key=self.s3_sec_key)

    if self.source_as_stage:

        no_of_dir = []

        try:
            bucket = s3_object.list_objects(Bucket=self.s3_bucket, Prefix=self.file_path, Delimiter='/')
            print("object bucket list >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", bucket)
        except Exception as e:
            self.propagate_log_msg('check [%s] and Source File Location Path' % e)

        for directory in bucket['CommonPrefixes']:
            no_of_dir.append(str(directory['Prefix']).rsplit('/', 2)[-2])

        print(no_of_dir)

        no_of_dir.sort(reverse=True)
        latest_dir = no_of_dir[0]

        self.convert_source_as_stage(latest_dir)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exit(-1)
```

def convert_source_as_stage(self, latest_file):

```
    source_file_format = str(self.metadata['source_file_format']).lower()+'_format' if self.metadata['source_file_format'] is not None else 'pipe_format'
    url = 's3://{bucket}/{location}/{dir_}'.format(location=self.s3_file_loc.strip("/"),
                                                   bucket=self.s3_bucket, dir_=latest_file)
    print("formateed url>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", url)
    file_name_dw = str(latest_file.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

    print("File_Name>>>>>>>>>>>>>", file_name_dw)
    print("Source file format :", source_file_format)
    print("source url: ", url)

    self.create_stage = """

                  CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE {sa}.{table} URL='{url}'
                  CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='{access_key}' AWS_SECRET_KEY='{secret}')
                  FILE_FORMAT = {file};
                  // create or replace stage {sa}.{table}
                  //   file_format = (type = 'csv' field_delimiter = '|' record_delimiter = '\\n');

                  """.format(sa=self.ss_cd, table=self.table.lower(), access_key=self.s3_acc_key, secret=self.s3_sec_key,
                             url=url, file=source_file_format, filename=str(self.metadata['source_table']))

    """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
            '''CONNECT TO SNOWFLAKE''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

    print("Create Stage Statement :", self.create_stage)

    con = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=self.USER,
        password=self.PASSWORD,
        account=self.ACCOUNT,
    )

    self.propagate_log_msg("Env metadata = [%s]" % self.env_metadata)

    """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    '''REFRESH DDL''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    try:

        file_format_full_path = os.path.join(self.root, 'sql', str(source_file_format)+'.sql')
        self.create_file_format = open(file_format_full_path, 'r').read()

        self.create_schema = "CREATE schema if not exists {db_lz}.{sa}".format(sa=self.ss_cd, db_lz=self.db_lz)

        env_sql = 'USE database {db_lz}'.format(db_lz=self.db_lz)
        self.propagate_log_msg(env_sql)
        con.cursor().execute(env_sql)
        con.cursor().execute(self.create_schema)

        env_sql = 'USE schema {schema}'.format(schema=self.ss_cd)
        self.propagate_log_msg(env_sql)
        con.cursor().execute(env_sql)

        con.cursor().execute(self.create_file_format)
        con.cursor().execute(self.create_stage)

    except snowflake.connector.ProgrammingError as e:
        self.propagate_log_msg('Invalid sql, fix sql and retry')
        self.propagate_log_msg(e)
        exit()
    except KeyError:
        self.propagate_log_msg(traceback.format_exc())
        self.propagate_log_msg('deploy_ods is not set in schedule metadata, assuming it is False')
    except Exception as e:
        self.propagate_log_msg('unhandled exception, debug')
        self.propagate_log_msg(traceback.format_exc())
        exit()
    else:
        self.propagate_log_msg(
            "Successfully dropped and recreated table/stage for [{sa}.{table}]".format(sa=self.ss_cd,
                                                                                  table=self.table))`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can take a step back and give a bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve.  That will help others in order to give good advice.

Best practice is to create *one* Snowflake `STAGE` for the whole bucket.  The `STAGE` object then mirrors the bucket object.  If your setup needs eg. different permissions for different parts of the bucket, then it can make sense to create multiple stages with different access rights.

It looks like the purpose of setting up stages is to import S3 objects into Snowflake tables.  This is done with the `COPY INTO <table>` command, and that command has two options for selecting objects/filenames to import:

1. `FILES = ( '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ] )`
2. `PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>'`

I suggest you put your effort into the `COPY INTO <table>` parameters instead of creating excess amounts of `STAGE` objects in the database.

You should also take a serious look into ***Snowpipes***.  Snowpipes does the job importing S3 objects near-realtime into Snowflake tables with `COPY INTO <table>` commands triggered by S3 eg. create object events.  Snowpipes cost less than warehouses as they are not dedicated resources.
Simple and effective.